# Split list into overlapping sublists

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to split a list into overlapping sublists! I want to generate a first sublist with a specified number of elements. Then I want to shift one element to the right and generate an overlapping sublist. ... and so on, until the end. All sublists should have the same length.
Just as an example:

```
{1, 6, 3, 6, 8, 5, 3}
```

I would like to obtain the following:

```
{{1, 6, 3, 6}, {6, 3, 6, 8}, {3, 6, 8, 5}, {6, 8, 5, 3}}
```

I have no idea how to tackle the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first sublist here has length 4, and the others have length 5. Are you sure you meant that?

Comment: I corrected the question! You are right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Partition[{1, 6, 3, 6, 8, 5, 3}, 4, 1]
```

is probably what you want. It returns:

```
{{1, 6, 3, 6}, {6, 3, 6, 8}, {3, 6, 8, 5}, {6, 8, 5, 3}}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am a bit embarrassed that I didn't figure that out myself.

Comment: These things are obvious *when you know the answer*.

Comment: I mean it was written in the documentation. I just misunderstood what is said there. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Niki, Could I just nudge you to accept this answer, if it's all sorted? I don't like seeing those horrible grey squares in my "answers" list on my user page :P

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {1, 6, 3, 6, 8, 5, 3};
```

Using `SequenceCases` (new in 10.1)

```
SequenceCases[list, {Repeated[_, {4}]}, Overlaps -> True]
```

{{1, 6, 3, 6}, {6, 3, 6, 8}, {3, 6, 8, 5}, {6, 8, 5, 3}}

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use `ListCorrelate` and `CoefficientArrays`:

```
list = {1, 6, 3, 6, 8, 5, 3};

Normal@CoefficientArrays[ListCorrelate[{x, y, z, w}, list], {x, y, z, w}][[2]]

(*{{1, 6, 3, 6}, {6, 3, 6, 8}, {3, 6, 8, 5}, {6, 8, 5, 3}}*)
```

Or using `Table`:

```
With[{n = 4, s = 1}, 
     Table[#[[i ;; i + n - 1]], {i, 1, Length@# - n + 1, s}] &@list]

(*{{1, 6, 3, 6}, {6, 3, 6, 8}, {3, 6, 8, 5}, {6, 8, 5, 3}}*)
```